# Building JavaFX UI dynamically on the fly

Tags: xml, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I am a novice to JavaFX. Still fiddling around a few samples to try and decide if that works out for the application that we are trying to build. 
First phase of our app is kind of a data entry phase where the users will be poised with a lot of questions and his responses are recorded. The catch here is that another team is building the question set and these questions are in an XML, like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userData>    
<question id="Q1" type ="desc">
    <text>Enter the name of the Component</text>
</question>
<question id ="Q2" type ="list">
    <text>Select mechanism type</text>
    <choices>
        <choice> Type 1 </choice>
        <choice> Type 2 </choice>
        <choice> Type 3 </choice>
        <choice> Type 4 </choice>
    </choices>
</question>
<question id ="Q5" type="yesNo">
    <text> Whether the parts have been verified by the supervisor? </text>
</question>
<question id ="Q6" type="yesNo">
    <text> Whether the component is available within the domicile </text>
</question>
<question id ="Q7" type="value">
    <text> Enter the quantity </text>
</question>
<question id ="Q8" type="value">
    <text> Enter the unit price </text>
</question>
</userData>
```

It corresponds to various fields like having a boolean radio button if its a yesNo type, a dropdown in case of list, a text field for values and so on. These questions can change depending on the user so the user can configure the questions through this file.

The idea is to load this xml during the application start, parse them and build appropriate UI Components on the fly. Can this be achieved through JavaFX? I made a small prototype of this app using an FXML file built through SceneBuilder. But the trick is to generate the FXML file  required to build this UI Components for queries programmatic-ally after parsing the Questions XML file which was loaded during the start up.

What is a good starting to point  in achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can take to this.

One is to simply parse the XML file, and create the FX controls in Java code as you go. This isn't too bad an approach, but you will not have any FXML at all. The basic idea is that you create a [`DocumentBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html), use it to parse your xml file to a [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), which is an in-memory model of the xml document. You can use that to iterate through the xml elements, and create the appropriate JavaFX UI element for each xml element, adding them to some `Pane`.

The other approach is to use an Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformation to transform your `XML` file into `FXML`. I am certainly no expert in this technology, but the idea is pretty straightforward:

Define an `xsl` file that basically defines what your `FXML` file should look like based on the contents of your `xml` file. Again, I am not really familiar with the details of `xsl`, but something like this appears to work for your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="import">
            java.lang.*
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="import">
            javafx.scene.layout.*
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="import">
            javafx.scene.control.*
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="import">
            javafx.geometry.Insets
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="import">
            javafx.collections.FXCollections
        </xsl:processing-instruction>

        <GridPane hgap="5" vgap="5" fx:id="form" fx:controller="xml2fx.FormController">         
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="NEVER" />
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <padding>
                <Insets top="10" bottom="10" left="10" right="10"/>
            </padding>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="//text"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//question"/>

        </GridPane>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <Label text="{.}" wrapText="true" textAlignment="RIGHT"
            GridPane.columnIndex="0"
            GridPane.rowIndex="{count(../preceding-sibling::question)}" />  
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="controlCoords">
            <GridPane.columnIndex>1</GridPane.columnIndex>
            <GridPane.rowIndex>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::question)"/>
            </GridPane.rowIndex>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="question[@type='desc']">
        <TextArea fx:id="{@id}" id="{@id}">
            <xsl:call-template name="controlCoords" />
        </TextArea>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="question[@type='list']">
        <ComboBox fx:id="{@id}" id="{@id}">
            <xsl:call-template name="controlCoords" />
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <xsl:for-each select="choices/choice">
                        <String fx:value="{.}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ComboBox>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="question[@type='value']">
        <TextField fx:id="{@id}" id="{@id}">
            <xsl:call-template name="controlCoords" />
        </TextField>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="question[@type='yesNo']">
        <CheckBox fx:id="{@id}" id="{@id}">
            <xsl:call-template name="controlCoords" />
        </CheckBox> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you just need to create a `Transformer` from that `xsl` file (I named it `xml2fxml.xsl`). The `transform` method will read the `xml` file, transform it according to the rules in the `xsl` file, and send the output to an output stream. You just need a little trickery to pipe that to an input stream and instruct the `FXMLLoader` to read the generated `fxml` from it:

```
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            final PipedOutputStream transformOutput = new PipedOutputStream();
            final PipedInputStream fxmlInputStream = new PipedInputStream(transformOutput);

            Thread transformThread = new Thread( () -> {
                try {
                    StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("xml2fxml.xsl"));
                    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsltSource);
                    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                    StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("questionnaire.xml"));
                    StreamResult transformerResult = new StreamResult(transformOutput);
                    transformer.transform(xmlSource, transformerResult);
                    transformOutput.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            transformThread.start();

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent root = loader.load(fxmlInputStream);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update:** (Also note slight updates to the `xsl` above)

While this is quite slick, it is almost too transparent in that it makes it difficult to get access to the form controls in the controller. You need to do a bit of ugly examination of the contents of the root element of the FXML-defined scene graph in order to find the correct elements.

This example uses some reflection to get at the values; you could also do it with a lot of `instanceof` tests and some casting. It also gets at the controls by "knowing" that they are all in column 1, which really violates the separation of view and controller; it might be better to have some convention on the `id` assigned to the controls (that distinguishes them from the `Label`s) and use that instead.

```
package xml2fx;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class FormController {

    private static final String SELECTED_VALUE = "yes" ;
    private static final String UNSELECTED_VALUE = "no" ;

    @FXML
    private GridPane form ;

    private final Map<String, Control> controls = new HashMap<>();
    private final List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    public void initialize() {
        for (Node node : form.getChildren()) {
            if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == 1) { // all form controls are in column 1
                if (node instanceof Control) {
                    String id = node.getId();
                    controls.put(id, (Control)node);
                    ids.add(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getIds() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(ids);
    }

    public String getUserValue(String id) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Control control = controls.get(id);
        if (control == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No control with id "+id);
        return getValueForControl(control);
    }

    private String getValueForControl(Control control) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        if (isTextControl(control)) {
            return getTextControlValue(control);
        } else if (isSelectable(control)) {
            return getSelectableValue(control);
        } else if (hasSelectionModel(control)) {
            return getSelectedValue(control);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported control class: "+control.getClass().getName());
    }

    private boolean isTextControl(Control control) {
        // TextAreas, TextFields, etc:
        return control instanceof TextInputControl ;
    }

    private String getTextControlValue(Control control) {
        return ((TextInputControl) control).getText();
    }

    private boolean isSelectable(Control control) {
        // ToggleButtons, CheckBoxes...
        for (Method method :  control.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().equals("isSelected") 
                    && method.getReturnType() == boolean.class) {
                return true ;
            }
        }
        return false ;
    }

    private String getSelectableValue(Control control) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Method isSelectedMethod = control.getClass().getMethod("isSelected");
        boolean selected = (Boolean) isSelectedMethod.invoke(control);
        if (selected) {
            return SELECTED_VALUE ;
        } else {
            return UNSELECTED_VALUE ;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasSelectionModel(Control control) {
        // ComboBoxes, ListViews, TableViews, etc:
        for (Method method : control.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if (method.getName().equals("getSelectionModel")) {
                return true ;
            }
        }
        return false ;
    }

    private String getSelectedValue(Control control) throws ReflectiveOperationException  {
        Method selectionModelMethod = control.getClass().getMethod("getSelectionModel");
        SelectionModel<?> selectionModel = (SelectionModel<?>) selectionModelMethod.invoke(control);
        Object selectedItem = selectionModel.getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedItem == null) {
            return "" ;
        } else {
            return selectedItem.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and I got to see something out of the box ! :)

Comment: You sir are genius :) Amazing solution. And thumbs up for the detailed explanation, it definitely did bring in additional clarity !

Comment: Interesting idea - I would not have thought to perform an XSLT on a data feed to generate the UI for representing it.

Comment: Just a quick question @James_D , Did you use any tool to generate the XSL? or Manually?

Comment: No, just typed it in.

Comment: If you want to use this approach, by the way, you may need to think quite hard about the controller, or retrieving the values from the form. It's not obvious how to do that.

Comment: True that. I have to break my head in wiring the controllers into it. I haven't reached that stage yet. But i am already facing problems trying to introduce <TitledPane> for different categories of questions now, as the number of questions have already grown to 50, i thought its a good idea to categorize them under different <TitledPane>, somehow stuck in XSLT for that :|

Comment: @James_D Any pointers on how to generate the controller classes and wire them to the generated FXML ? :D

Comment: Thanks a lot @James_D. Didn't knew it would be so complicated when i started :|

Answer (score -1):

```
    (creating ui)
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import java.io.File;

    public class XMLJavaFXLoader {
        protected static double minWidth;
        protected  static double minHeight;
        protected static Class controller;
        protected static String stageTitle;
        protected static Scene scene;
        public XMLJavaFXLoader(String filename) throws Exception {
            Document loaded = LoadXMLDocument(filename);
            getAttributes(loaded);
            minWidth = scene.getWidth();
            minHeight = scene.getHeight();
        }
        public static void getAttributes(Document doc) throws Exception {

            XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

            Element stage = (Element) path.evaluate("Stage",doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            stageTitle = stage.getAttribute("title");
            String controllerName = stage.getAttribute("controller");
            controller = Class.forName(controllerName);
            Element rootElement = (Element) path.evaluate("*",stage,XPathConstants.NODE);
            Pane root;
            if(rootElement.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                root = new VBox();
            }
            else root = new HBox();

            NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",rootElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                getChildren(root,curChild);
            }
            scene = new Scene(root,Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("width")),Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("height")));
        }
        private static void getChildren(Pane parent,Element curNode) throws Exception {
            if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
                Label newLabel = new Label(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newLabel);
            }
            else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Textfield")){
                TextField newTextField = new TextField(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                newTextField.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newTextField);
            }
            else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("button")){
                Button newButton = new Button(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                newButton.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newButton);
            }
            else{

                XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

                Pane newNode;
                if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                    newNode = new VBox();
                }
                else newNode = new HBox();

                NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",curNode,XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                    getChildren(newNode,curChild);
                }
                parent.getChildren().add(newNode);
            }
        }
        public static Document  LoadXMLDocument(String filename) throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            File myFile = new File(filename);
            Document doc = builder.parse(myFile);
            return doc;
        }
    }



    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import java.io.File;

    public class XMLJavaFXLoader {
        protected static double minWidth;
        protected  static double minHeight;
        protected static Class controller;
        protected static String stageTitle;
        protected static Scene scene;
        public XMLJavaFXLoader(String filename) throws Exception {
            Document loaded = LoadXMLDocument(filename);
            getAttributes(loaded);
            minWidth = scene.getWidth();
            minHeight = scene.getHeight();
        }
        public static void getAttributes(Document doc) throws Exception {

            XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

            Element stage = (Element) path.evaluate("Stage",doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            stageTitle = stage.getAttribute("title");
            String controllerName = stage.getAttribute("controller");
            controller = Class.forName(controllerName);
            Element rootElement = (Element) path.evaluate("*",stage,XPathConstants.NODE);
            Pane root;
            if(rootElement.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                root = new VBox();
            }
            else root = new HBox();

            NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",rootElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                getChildren(root,curChild);
            }
            scene = new Scene(root,Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("width")),Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("height")));
        }
        private static void getChildren(Pane parent,Element curNode) throws Exception {
            if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
                Label newLabel = new Label(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newLabel);
            }
            else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Textfield")){
                TextField newTextField = new TextField(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                newTextField.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newTextField);
            }
            else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("button")){
                Button newButton = new Button(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                newButton.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newButton);
            }
            else{

                XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

                Pane newNode;
                if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                    newNode = new VBox();
                }
                else newNode = new HBox();

                NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",curNode,XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                    getChildren(newNode,curChild);
                }
                parent.getChildren().add(newNode);
            }
        }
        public static Document  LoadXMLDocument(String filename) throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            File myFile = new File(filename);
            Document doc = builder.parse(myFile);
            return doc;
        }
    }

    main class

    public class Main extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Creating scene and controller from XML...");
            XMLJavaFXLoader loader = new XMLJavaFXLoader("layout02.xml");

             System.out.println("Initialising stage...");
            primaryStage.setMinWidth(loader.minWidth);
            primaryStage.setMinHeight(loader.minHeight);
            primaryStage.setTitle(loader.stageTitle);
            primaryStage.setScene(loader.scene);

            System.out.println("Showing stage...");
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }

    Controller

    public class Controller implements JavaFXController {
        public void btnAddClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnAddClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        public void btnMultiplyClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnMultiplyClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        public void btnFactorXClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnFactorXClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        public void btnDiffClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnDiffClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        private Scene scene;
        private Label lblOutput;`your text`
        private TextField txtX;
        private TextField txtY;

        @Override
        public void setScene(Scene scene) {
            this.scene = scene;
            lblOutput = (Label) scene.lookup("#lblOutput");
            txtX = (TextField) scene.lookup("#txtX");
            txtY = (TextField) scene.lookup("#txtY");
        }``
    }

<!-- end snippet -->

                NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",curNode,XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                    getChildren(newNode,curChild);
                }
                parent.getChildren().add(newNode);
            }
        }
        public static Document  LoadXMLDocument(String filename) throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            File myFile = new File(filename);
            Document doc = builder.parse(myFile);
            return doc;
        }
    }



    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    import java.io.File;

    public class XMLJavaFXLoader {
        protected static double minWidth;
        protected  static double minHeight;
        protected static Class controller;
        protected static String stageTitle;
        protected static Scene scene;
        public XMLJavaFXLoader(String filename) throws Exception {
            Document loaded = LoadXMLDocument(filename);
            getAttributes(loaded);
            minWidth = scene.getWidth();
            minHeight = scene.getHeight();
        }
        public static void getAttributes(Document doc) throws Exception {

            XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

            Element stage = (Element) path.evaluate("Stage",doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            stageTitle = stage.getAttribute("title");
            String controllerName = stage.getAttribute("controller");
            controller = Class.forName(controllerName);
            Element rootElement = (Element) path.evaluate("*",stage,XPathConstants.NODE);
            Pane root;
            if(rootElement.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                root = new VBox();
            }
            else root = new HBox();

            NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",rootElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                getChildren(root,curChild);
            }
            scene = new Scene(root,Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("width")),Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("height")));
        }
        private static void getChildren(Pane parent,Element curNode) throws Exception {
            if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
                Label newLabel = new Label(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newLabel);
            }
            else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Textfield")){
                TextField newTextField = new TextField(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                newTextField.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newTextField);
            }
            else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("button")){
                Button newButton = new Button(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
                newButton.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
                parent.getChildren().add(newButton);
            }
            else{

                XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

                Pane newNode;
                if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                    newNode = new VBox();
                }
                else newNode = new HBox();

                NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",curNode,XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                    getChildren(newNode,curChild);
                }
                parent.getChildren().add(newNode);
            }
        }
        public static Document  LoadXMLDocument(String filename) throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            File myFile = new File(filename);
            Document doc = builder.parse(myFile);
            return doc;
        }
    }


 Controller

    public class Controller implements JavaFXController {
        public void btnAddClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnAddClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        public void btnMultiplyClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnMultiplyClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        public void btnFactorXClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnFactorXClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        public void btnDiffClicked(ActionEvent event) {
            lblOutput.setText("btnDiffClicked, X="
                    + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
        }

        private Scene scene;
        private Label lblOutput;`your text`
        private TextField txtX;
        private TextField txtY;

        @Override
        public void setScene(Scene scene) {
            this.scene = scene;
            lblOutput = (Label) scene.lookup("#lblOutput");
            txtX = (TextField) scene.lookup("#txtX");
            txtY = (TextField) scene.lookup("#txtY");
        }``
    }
```

`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```html
CUSTOM POPUPS 
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.stage.Popup;

/**
 * CustomPopup is a control with a custom appearance and effects applied.
 * It is draggable by the title bar and can be closed by right clicking
 * on the title bar.
 */
public class CustomPopup extends Popup {
    // region Fields
    // A cached reference to the part of the control can be dragged by.
    private VBox topBox;
    // Message displayed on the control.
    private String message;
    // The initial point where the mouse was pressed.
    private Double anchorX, anchorY;
    // endregion

    public CustomPopup(String message) {
        // Very important - need to perform inherited initialisation.
        super();
        this.message = message;

        anchorX = new Double(0);
        anchorY = new Double(0);

        // Create the layout for this control.
        createLayout();
        // Logic for handling drag and drop behaviour.
        setBehaviour();
    }

    protected void createLayout() {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

        // region Add drop shadow effect to stack pane
        DropShadow shadow = new DropShadow();
        shadow.setRadius(10);
        shadow.setOffsetX(0);
        shadow.setOffsetY(0);
        shadow.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
        stackPane.setEffect(shadow);
        // endregion

        // region Create the title bar
        Label lblTitle= new Label("Custom Popup");
        topBox = new VBox();
        topBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        topBox.getChildren().add(lblTitle);
        Stop[] stops = new Stop[]{
                new Stop(0, Color.DARKGRAY),
                new Stop(1, Color.BLACK)};
        LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
        BackgroundFill titleBackground = new BackgroundFill(linearGradient, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
        topBox.setBackground(new Background(titleBackground));
        lblTitle.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        // endregion

        // region Place everything into the border pane
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(topBox);
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        BackgroundFill dlgBackground = new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGREY, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
        borderPane.setBackground(new Background(dlgBackground));
        borderPane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(
                Color.BLACK,
                BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
                new CornerRadii(5),
                new BorderWidths(2))));
        // endregion

        // region Add message to center of popup
        Label lblMessage = new Label(message);
        borderPane.setCenter(lblMessage);
        // endregion

        // Stack controls on top of each other
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(borderPane);

        getContent().add(stackPane);
    }

    protected void setBehaviour() {
        // region Dragging behaviour.
        // When press a mouse button, mark position of cursor relative to control.
        topBox.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            // If not dragging with "left" mouse button, don't proceed.
            if(event.getButton() != MouseButton.PRIMARY) return;

            // Remember offset/displacement/anchor relative to pop up's top left corner
            anchorX = event.getScreenX() - getX();
            anchorY = event.getScreenY() - getY();
        });

        // When mouse dragged (mouse button down & moved), update the position of control.
        topBox.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            // If not dragging with "left" mouse button, don't proceed.
            if(event.getButton() != MouseButton.PRIMARY) return;

            // Set top left corner of pop up so looks like moving at cursor

            setX(event.getScreenX() - anchorX);
            setY(event.getScreenY() - anchorY);

        });
        // endregion

        // Close popup if title bar clicked with secondary mouse button
        topBox.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) hide();
        });
    }
}
public class Controller {
    public Controller(Stage stage) {
        // Get a reference to the button.
        Button btnTooltip = (Button) stage.getScene().lookup("#button");

        // When button clicked, create and show the custom pop up.
        btnTooltip.setOnAction(event -> {
            CustomPopup popup = new CustomPopup("Time = " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime());
            popup.show(stage);
        });
    }
}

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Example02 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Scene createScene() {
        // Create root of the scene graph.
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Create button & attach a tool tip
        Button btnTooltip = new Button("Tooltip Button");
        btnTooltip.setId("button");
        btnTooltip.setTooltip(new Tooltip("This button has a tool tip :)"));

        root.getChildren().addAll(
                btnTooltip
        );

        return new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Example 2");
        primaryStage.setScene(createScene());

        Controller controller = new Controller(primaryStage);

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.