# JavaFX/ScalaFX, WPF like Scene creation

Tags: java, wpf, javafx, fxml

In Windows Presentation Foundation for each xaml file there is a code behind file. In JavaFX, however, the controller is more or less independent from the fxml file, it is only specified by the fx:controller attribute.

In WPF, you can create controls/windows by calling their constructors. In JavaFX, however, when you want to create a scene, you have to use the FXMLLoader class and load the fxml by specifying its path. IMHO it is very illogical, inconvenient and error-prone. Is there a design decision behind this?

I could create a new class that would inherit from Scene and initially load `getClass().getSimpleName() + ".fxml"` inside itself and set itself as the controller. Then I could inherit from this class for each window.
Is there anything wrong with it? Why isn't this solution offered by the core lib?

Comment: This question probably just lends itself to opinion and probably isn't right for this forum. My opinion is that your approach is more appropriate for a framework than for the core library. (It's more or less how [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) works.) What about FXML files that aren't intended to make up an entire `Scene`? What if you want your controller to come from another source (e.g. a Spring bean factory)? What if you want to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321871/building-javafx-ui-dynamically-on-the-fly/24329725#24329725)?

Comment: That said, while WPF allows you to instantiate UI elements in procedural code by calling their constructors, you probably will never need to do such thing due to the high composability of the UI and WPF's DataBinding and Data Templating capabilities.

Comment: @James_D WPF resolves that by having each XAML file have a single root element and the resulting CLR type that is created is defined by that root element. For example, a XAML file that starts with `<Window ....>` is going to produce a CLR class derived from `System.Windows.Window`. Regarding the composability issue, as mentioned above, properly designed technologies like WPF have built-in features to cater for that such as Data Templating and do not require the abominable hacks required in inferior incapable technologies.

Comment: @DavidFrank is your suggestion substantially different from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components)?

Comment: @James_D No, what I'd like to achieve is to have a concise way of defining controls and scenes without code duplication. The effect would be the same. The difference would be that you wouldn't have to write the same loading code over and over again (and I'm wondering why there is no built-in way of doing this).

Comment: I think simply because as a general philosophy Oracle chooses not to mandate one particular way of using the library over any other, instead preferring to make it as easy as possible for framework developers to do that. That's different to Microsoft's approach, but neither is particularly more valid than the other. The aforementioned [afterburner.fx framework](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) provides exactly what you're looking for - and a whole lot more - with just 3 simple classes. Other frameworks are still able to provide solutions for other use cases.