# Embedded JavaFX, injecting views and Dagger 2

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection, raspberry-pi, dagger-2

I am developing a set of products to be run on an embedded industrial system where one code base will need to be slightly altered to become multiple different apps (~20 products). It will use Java 13 and JavaFX, and I intend to use Dagger 2 to inject different FXML views and controllers depending to create the different products.  For example, one product may have an input form that contains a Zip Code TextField, while a variant may instead have a ComboBox rather than a Text Field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TextField promptText="First Name" />
            <TextField promptText="Last Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField promptText="Zip Code" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Include inflation factor" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Do Something" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

For both variants, the controller will be very similar, and only the handling of the Zip Code TextField vs ComboBox will be different.

In other variants, the Event Handler of the "Do Something" button will perform different actions depending on the product variant. I would like to be able to define these variations at build time so that the Gradle-based build server could specify which variation to build.

How might I go about this using Dagger 2, and is this the most suitable solution?

Comment: Sort of related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321871/building-javafx-ui-dynamically-on-the-fly I wrote that a few years back as "proof of concept", but it might be an approach you could try for this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about Dagger 2, but I know how to do it with common JavaFx Api:

"Common.fxml":

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<fx:root spacing="10.0" type="HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button text="xxx" onAction="#handleXxx"/>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Implementations of variants:

```java
public class Variant1 {

    @FXML
    private void handleXxx() {
        // print 111
    }
}

public class Variant2 {

    @FXML
    private void handleXxx() {
        // print 222
    }
}

// in main
FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Common.fxml"));
Variant1 variant1 = new Variant1();
loader1.setController(variant1);
Parent p1 = loader1.load();

FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Common.fxml"));
Variant2 variant2 = new Variant2();
loader2.setController(variant2);
Parent p2 = loader2.load();
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to have variations in the layout (particularly in the choice of controls being used), not variations in how to handle events.